# How to append img to div and fade In

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an image slider, by clicking on thumb above I am getting src of that image and appending it to the div where I want to show that as big image,
It is appending to that div but I want to append and fade in and when I click on new image the previous one should fade out. How can I achieve that?

Image slider:

[image: Image slider]

```
 <div id='main'>
        <div class="thumbsImg">
            <ul class="ulthumbs">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/a1.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a2.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a3.jpeg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a4.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a5.png" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a6.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a7.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a8.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="img/a9.jpg" width='150' height="80">
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>            
        <div id='imgBody'></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbsImg {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;   
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  }

ul.ulthumbs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.ulthumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#imgBody{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: pink;

}
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function (){

    $('.ulthumbs li img').on('click', function(){


       $('#imgBody').html('');
       var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

       var img = "<img src='"+imgSrc+"' width='100%' height='auto'>";

       $('#imgBody').append(img);


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your JQuery code to make use of `fadeOut()` & `fadeIn` functions.

[Read about it here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```
$('.ulthumbs li img').on('click', function(){
  $( "#imgBody" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
   $('#imgBody').html('');
   var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
   var img = "<img src='"+imgSrc+"' width='100%' height='auto'>";
   $( "#imgBody" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
   $('#imgBody').append(img);
});
```

Check the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/amVRNw)

You could also add your own fadein/out time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not providing this in JQuery, I'm not familiar with it at all; it should be straightforward enough to "translate" it, though.

The idea here is that, rather than appending a new `img` element to the `#imgBody` element with each click, you instead start with an "empty" placholder image already in place, with its `opacity` set to `0`. On the first image click, the `src` property is set to that of the clicked image and the class setting the `opacity` is removed. Then, on each subsequent image click, the class that set the `opacity` is added, the `src` is changed and the class is removed again.

```js
((img,wait,first)=>document.querySelector(".ulthumbs").addEventListener("click",evt=>{
  if(!wait){
    wait=1;
    if(!first)img.classList.add("hide");
    setTimeout(()=>{
      img.src=evt.target.src;
      img.classList.remove("hide");
      setTimeout(()=>first=wait=0,first?0:500);
    },first?0:500);
  }
},0))(document.querySelector("#imgBody>img"),0,1);
```

```css
.thumbsImg{
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow-x:auto;
  width:100%;
}
ul.ulthumbs{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.ulthumbs>li{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}
#imgBody {
  background:pink;
  margin-top:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}
#imgBody>img{
  height:auto;
  transition:opacity .5s;
  width:auto;
  max-width:100%;
}
#imgBody>img.hide{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <div class="thumbsImg">
    <ul class="ulthumbs">
      <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/320?image=0" width='150' height="80"></li>
      <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/320?image=10" width='150' height="80"></li>
      <li><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/320?image=20" width='150' height="80"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="imgBody">
    <img class="hide" height="320" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" width="600">
  </div>
</div>
```